# Getting EOF after calling Racket function with-out-to-string

Tags: racket

I can't figure out why the below code would first print "eof" (On the interactions window). I am using DrRacket.

```
(find-first-path (car 
    (regexp-split #px"\n" 
        (with-output-to-string
            (λ () (system "find /usr/lib/ -name
libpython2.7.so"))))))
```

Comment: on the interaction windows? Do you mean a dialog? If yes, can you attach a screenshot of it?

Comment: Thanks, but John has answered the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `system` library function starts a shell process that takes its input
from (current-input-port). In DrRacket, this causes the creation of a (short-
lived) subwindow of the interactions window into which you can type input that
you want to be treated as input to the subprocess.

So, for instance, try running this program

```
#lang racket

(system "cat")
```

Each line that you type into the input window will wind up being piped to the
cat process. When you're finished, though, you need a way to send an EOF to
the subprocess. This is what the "EOF" button on the right does.

If you don't want to see this window, you can create an empty input stream
to your subprocess, e.g.:

```
(parameterize ([current-input-port (open-input-string "")])
  (system "find /usr/lib/ -name libpython2.7.so"))
```

Comment: I also see this message at the footer of DrRacket "subprocess: forbidden (execute) access to /bin/sh". I wont like to see this message too.

Comment: I can't be sure, but I suspect this message is coming from the automatic compilation that DrRacket has enabled by default. You can disable it, but you might not want to; it would also prevent the automatic detection of other syntax errors. I would suggest that if it doesn't bother you too much, you ignore it.